# How to use op.execute in alembic upgrade

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, database-migration

I have a table named `orders` which has a column named amount which initially contains certain `null` values.

I am converting it to `nullable=False` with a default value of 0 for any new orders but in the existing table, there already are finite null values present.

I want to convert these null values to 0 in my table before I can upgrade the database.

```py
"""empty message

Revision ID: 6e5c574cbfb8
Revises: 35f427e85075
Create Date: 2019-03-24 11:09:42.707206

"""

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy_utils
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '6e5c574cbfb8'
down_revision = '35f427e85075'


def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.execute("UPDATE orders SET amount=0 WHERE amount=null")
    op.alter_column('orders', 'amount',
               existing_type=postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION(precision=53),
               nullable=False,
               )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('orders', 'amount',
               existing_type=postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION(precision=53),
               nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

But this still shows error, any assistance regarding how do I use op.execute properly?

Comment: What is the error? Please include full traceback.

Comment: Please show the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
UPDATE orders SET amount=0 WHERE amount is null;
```